# Spring Mail Generating Null Pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to configure mail in Spring and keep getting a null pointer exception.  My suspicion is that it can't find the "mailSender" bean but I could be way off.  My configuration is as follows:

**web.xml**

```
    <!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logVerbosityLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>ERROR</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<beans:bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <beans:property name="host" value="mail.company.com"/>
</beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

**SendMailTest.java**

```
package company.test;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.invocation.InvocationOnMock;
import org.mockito.stubbing.Answer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext;

import company.AppListener;

public class SendMailTest {
private static final Logger logger = AppListener.getLogger();

@Mock
private ServletContextEvent mockServletContextEvent;
private final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
@Mock
private ServletContext mockServletContext;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
    initMocks(this);
    map.clear();

    when(mockServletContextEvent.getServletContext()).thenReturn(mockServletContext);
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
        public Object answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation)
            throws Throwable {
            final String key = (String) invocation.getArguments()[0];
            final Object value = invocation.getArguments()[1];
            return map.put(key, value);
        }
    }).when(mockServletContext).setAttribute(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyObject());
    Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
        public Object answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation)
            throws Throwable {
            final Object value = invocation.getArguments()[0];
            return map.remove(value);
        }
    }).when(mockServletContext).removeAttribute(Mockito.anyString());
}

@Autowired
private MailSender mailSender;


@Test
public void testSendSimpleEmaill() {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();

    String name = "John Doe";
    message.setFrom("john.doe@company.com");
    message.setTo("jane.doe@company2.com");
    message.setSubject("Test Email from Spring");
    message.setText("Will email ever work?");

    try {
        mailSender.send(message);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at company.test.SendMailTest.testSendSimpleEmaill(SendMailTest.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yu need to put the configurations in your test class, also you whould like to copy your context file to the root of your test class (just file resolution, when the spring runners starts needs to load your context file)..your test class should look like this...

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "applicationContext.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class FacadeTest {

    private String phoneNumber = "111111115";

    @Autowired 
    private BussinesDelegate bussinesDelegate;

    @Test
    public void runTest(){
        this.fullTest(phoneNumber, "aaaaa");
    }

    public void fullTest(String phoneNumber, String answer){
        try {
            bmoaBussinesDelegate.processMessage("127.0.0.1", phoneNumber, "camicase" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and dont forget to check your dependencies!

```
<!-- Junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

The cool thing about spring, its that its IOC container can probide the same behavior as a full Java EE compliant server without needing a server, and basically what the runner does is to load the context manually, the same way you could do ir in a standole app with spring ;)

Comment: You're wellcome, une last thing, if you copy the context file to the test folder be always aware to have the same file there and in WEB-INF, otherwise you could get different configurations for the deployed and tested version.

Answer (score 1):

When you're running the test with JUnit, Spring isn't loaded at all, so the autowired fields aren't being set. To run spring in a test, look into the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.

You can also create your own instance of JavaMailSenderImpl within the setUp method and assign it to `mailSender`

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I added the following packages: `import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`  [link](http://lstierneyltd.com/blog/development/examples/unit-testing-spring-apps-with-runwithspringjunit4classrunner-class/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I added the following packages: `import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`   but got the same error message.  
I tried instructions on this [link](http://lstierneyltd.com/blog/development/examples/unit-testing-spring-apps-with-runwithspringjunit4classrunner-class/) and it seems to ask for these annotations `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"daos.xml"})` however, I'm not sure if they're necessary?